# Customer Card save in Stripe with Stripe JS

Tags: angular, laravel, stripe-payments

I have angular as frontend.
From there I'm getting customer cards details and creating a token

> const { token, error } = await stripe.createToken(this.card, options);

I have Laravel as Backend

I need to save the customer card details in stripe and need to save the reponse details like last 4 digits.
It should be feasible to save the multiple cards for the customer.

Note:Initially only the card details need to saved and payment happens later.

I have gone through the documents,but I didn't understand how to use the token that I get front frontend to save the customer card details.

Hoping for the solutions
Thanks.

Comment: You should not save the card details. The token is all you need to make a charge.

Comment: @Bryan I’m not really sure what purpose your comment serves? Saving card details for future purchases is a pretty common activity, and something that Stripe themselves facilitates: https://stripe.com/docs/saving-cards

Comment: @MartinBean I think you missed my point. It could also be I misinterpreted the question. What I mean is: YOU as a developer should not be saving a consumer's credit card details on your servers. It is a huge security risk. Allowing a company like stripe to save a card for you is different (it's literally their business). See pci compliance faq for more details: https://www.pcicomplianceguide.org/faq/#14

Comment: @Bryan Yup, I’m aware of PCI compliance and the security best practice of not holding any payment instrument details if possible. I don’t think OP is looking to save the card details themselves (if _I’ve_ misinterpreted the question and you are, then heed Bryan’s advice: **don’t**). OP: Follow Stripe’s guide for saving cards their side.

Answer (score 1):

You use Stripe.js to generate a tokenized form of the user's card, which you can then pass to the backend and save to a Customer by following the steps here:

https://stripe.com/docs/saving-cards

Comment: Hi @tainted,Thanks for the reply.
I have gone through the link provided by you,
I have angular as frontend and Laravel as backend.
So I need to create any token using stripe.js and need to pass that token via API and need to create a customer with his card details in stripe.
So that I can retrieve the details like last 4 digits and so..on to show for the customer

Answer (score 0):

I am just working with the api recently. And the link my backend partner and I used is https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse. (the link contains all clientside/frontend codes you need that help me setup the frontend part eventually) Another one seems like an older api that stripe does not recommend.

You will end up getting a token and save it into your database associate with the client, and use the token (`customer id`) to retrieve information from stripe or make payment.
The retrieve information contains last4 digits, card type, billing details, etc. that you can use to display on frontend.

Comment: Hi @yunhai,Thanks for the reply.
There they had a form in PHP
But I get the card details from the angular side,since I cannot pass the details through our API,I will create a token.
I will pass the token to my backend and get the card details.
I'm trying to go in this flow.